# Activity should not be reloaded

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-view

I am making an android app. In this, on one layout I have many Edit texts and I have to fill data. On click of Edit text I want to open a layout having numeric keywords and give option to enter/fill data. On click of OK button in keyword layout I want to set data in that Edit text. Is it possible that we don't have to reload or refresh that activity???

Comment: I am sure I can't understand the question because I can't find the reason why you thought that the activity will  get reloaded for this.

Comment: By `reload/refresh` you mean you'll make a network call to get that data?

Comment: So you want to start a new activity with just that EditText and a Button, and not just open the Keyboard?

Comment: I have activity A(having Edit texts) over Activity B(having self made keyboard). I have to enter data in activity B's Edit text and set this text on Activity A's Edit text. By this process I don't want to reload Activity A to display updated data. Hope its clear now.

Answer (score 0):

you could use use dialog fragments for the keyboard layout. what are you using now?

Comment: Actually I have not started doing it yet. Could you please clarify how can I do it your way?

Comment: Creating a dialog fragment, to fill your edit text would not cause a onPause on your Activity. Check out the dialogfragment class, add a function in it to pass your edittext, then when you hit ok, fill the editext (with watever data that comes from your custom keyboard), look at this http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

Comment: you have not started but u want others to help you... stackoverflow is not meant for this. first try yourself then only post ur problem.